# How does react avoid using require("../../Path/To/Module"), and just use require("Module")

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

As far as I've seen, npm modules can be `require()` without a path:

```
require("module") // --> npm module
```

and local modules are `require()` using a path:

```
require("./module") // --> local module, in this directory
require("../../path/to/module") // path to directory
```

---

In react.js, modules are required without a path.  [See here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/ReactDOM.js) for example.  I'm wondering how they achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it uses [`rewrite-modules`](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-fbjs/plugins/rewrite-modules.js) Babel plugin with [`module-map`](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/master/packages/fbjs-scripts/gulp/module-map.js) module (see [**gulpfile.js**](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L65).)

There's also [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-map) Babel plugin that you can use to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: You can also use aliases with Webpack if you use it. (which is often the case with react + es6 + babel) [webpack.resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Webpack, you can add `path/to/modules` into `resolve.modulesDirectories` array and it will work similarly to requiring from `node_modules` instead of using relative paths.

`resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: ['path/to/modules', 'node_modules'],
},`

and then

`var foo = require('foo'); 
// Instead of:
// var foo = require('/path/to/modules/foo');
// or
// var foo = require('../../foo');`